# Converting JSON to Hashmap<String, POJO> using GWT

Tags: java, android, json, gwt, mgwt

```
SortedMap<String, VehicleData> hmap = new TreeMap<String, VehicleData>();
```

My JSON String sample:

```
 {
    "3": {
        "Field1": 12,
        "Field2": "value",
        "Field3": null
    },
    "test": {
        "Field1": 20,
        "Field2": "value",
        "Field3": "vit"
    }
}
```

I want to convert this string to HashMap declared above. Is there any method to convert directly from Json string to Hashmap?

Comment: you can try google GSON or jackson library for achieving the same.

Answer (score 0):

using Gson you can parse it eailsy at server side.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type= new TypeToken<Map<String, VehicleData>>(){}.getType();
Map<String,VehicleData> map = gson.fromJson(Your_JSON_STRING, type);
```

If you want client/server side serialize/deserialize JSON in GWT code.

In GWT 2.1.1 you can use [GWT AutoBean framework](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean)

```
String serializeToJson(Test test) 
{
    // Retrieve the AutoBean controller
    AutoBean<Test> bean = AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean(test);
    return AutoBeanCodex.encode(bean).getPayload();
}

Test deserializeFromJson(String json) 
{     
    AutoBean<Test> bean = AutoBeanCodex.decode(myFactory, Test.class, json);     
    return bean.as();   
}
```

I've not tried with complex and low level with Map, you can go with doc

`Finally if you want to gson on client side with GWT then you have to try` [bGwtGson](https://github.com/heroandtn3/bGwtGson) library

Comment: yeah its for Server-side Deserializing/serializing JSON with GWT not for the client.

Comment: @Christian Kuetbach you can deserializing/serialize with GWT AutoBean framework at client/server side, but i have not tried with complex Java Map

Comment: AutoBeans works, but they are some kind of buggy especially if you use Maps or Lists. Sometimes you will need to recreate the beans, f you modify the content of a map. And you should not work with concrete types. You should use the Map-Interface. In fact, I think AutoBeans are really buggy.

Comment: if you want to gson on client side then you have to try this library    https://github.com/heroandtn3/bGwtGson